# Asp.net mvc connect to webApi by httpClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, dotnet-httpclient

I have mvc application and webApi application. I need sign in in asp.net mvc through webApi. When i use this method:

```
public static string GetToken(LoginModelView login)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", login.Login ),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "Password", login.Password )
                        };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response =
                    client.PostAsync(URL + "/Token", content).Result;
                var responseJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var dictionaryToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(responseJson);
                string token = dictionaryToken["access_token"];
                return token;
            }
        }
```

My mvc don't bind model from view.
Action methods

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SignIn()
        {
            var login = new LoginModelView();
            return View("SignIn",login);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn(LoginModelView login)
        {
            string token = DirService.GetToken(login);

            Session["token"] = token;

            return RedirectToAction("success");
        }
```

It's model

```
public class LoginModelView
    {
        public string Login { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

It's my view

```
@model AdminTool.Models.LoginModelView
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>LoginModelView</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

when i don't use that method, everything is ok.
The same code works in another application.
Somebody can help me, please..

Comment: what do you mean by `don't bind model`. Is the action being called/hit?

Comment: I mean i get null instead filled object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that in `LoginModelView` class has `Login` Property and you create same object name `LoginModelView login` in controller.I change that code and its Work For Me.

Model:-

```
           [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult SignIn()
            {
                var loginModelView = new LoginModelView();
                return View("SignIn", loginModelView);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SignIn(LoginModelView loginModelView)
            {
                string token = DirService.GetToken(loginModelView);

                Session["token"] = token;

                return RedirectToAction("success");
            }
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thank you soo much !!!!                                                                                     Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

**I think you posting from data to get method(GetToken).**